# ログイン認証付き画像表示

Tags: javascript, html

HTMLであればセッション確認によりログイン判定はできます。
しかし画像の部分はログイン判定後のHTMLの中にで記載するのでログイン判定により出し分けはできません。もしくは直リンクでアクセスされたらそのまま表示されます。

画像についてのログイン判定後の出し分けはどのようにすればいいのでしょうか？
Googleで調べてみていますがいい記事が見つかりません。ご存知の方はご教示いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

認証やアクセス制御が必要な画像ファイルや他静的ファイルについては、全てアプリケーションを経由するよう仕向ける方法が一番単純でしょうか。

具体的には、取得する画像などコンテンツのURLを、ファイルへのパスではなく、アプリケーションにコンテンツのIDを渡して出力する方法となります。

Answer (score 1):

色々案はあるかと思うのですが、認証が必要な画像は全部Ajaxで送るように作る。というのが今風かつシンプルでいいのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

タグや文章を読むとHTML上のスクリプトといったクライアント側で認証しようとしているかのように見えますね。
画像ファイルと言っても通信はhttp/httpsです。
サーバー側に設定する権限があるならログインやセッションでの管理は可能です。

サーバーソフト(Apache等)側のBasic認証等の認証機能を使用してみてください。
ディレクトリ単位やファイル単位、正規表現でのアクセス制限や
拡張の仕方によってはハンドラーを使っての認証プログラムまでかなり細かく設定できます。

ログイン判定でアクセス権を付与した上で個別のファイルの表示を制限したいなら
アカウント情報で制限範囲を分けたBasic認証を設置するとか
アプリケーション(CGI)側で画像も含めてセッション情報を確認してファイルデータを返すとか方法はいくつか有ります。

おすすめは高速で負荷が低いBasic認証で対象ディレクトリ全体に制限をかけてしまう方法です。